# How to deal with Ajax data not arrive yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, fusioncharts

I have a chart that contain

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

console.log('{{ $cpe_mac }}');

var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}'});
ajax.done(function (data) {

console.log(data)

var array_hour_g_down = [];
var array_hour_g_up = [];
var array_hour_p_down = [];
var array_hour_p_up = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.hour_g_up.length; i++) {

    array_hour_g_down[i] = {"value":data.hour_g_down[i]};
    array_hour_g_up[i]   = {"value":data.hour_g_up[i]};
    array_hour_p_down[i] = {"value":data.hour_p_down[i]};
    array_hour_p_up[i]   = {"value":data.hour_p_up[i]};

}

var granular_time_network_day = new FusionCharts({
    "type": "msstackedcolumn2d",
    "renderAt": "granular-time-network",
    "width": "100%",
    "dataFormat": "json",
    "dataSource": {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Time-Based Bandwidth Usage",
            "subcaption": "Daily View",
            "xaxisname": data.month + ' ' + data.dth + ',' + ' '+ data.year,
            "yaxisname": "Bandwidth (in Megabytes)",
            "paletteColors": color_home_down+','+color_home_up+','+color_guest_down+','+color_guest_up,
                    // "numbersuffix": "MB",
                    "showvalues": "0",
                    "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                    "borderAlpha": "20",
                    "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                    "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                    "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                    "legendShadow": "0",
                    "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
                    "showXAxisLine": "1",
                    "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
                    "divlineColor": "#999999",
                    "divLineDashed": "1",
                    "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                    "subcaptionFontSize": "14"
                },
                "categories": [{
                    "category": [{
                        "label": "12am-2am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "2am-4am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "4am-6am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "6am-8am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "8am-10am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "10am-12pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "12pm-2pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "2pm-4pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "4pm-6pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "6pm-8pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "8pm-10pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "10pm-12am"
                    }]
                }],
                "dataset": [{
                    "dataset": [{
                        "seriesname": "Home Network - Downlink",
                        "data": array_hour_p_down
                    }, {
                        "seriesname": "Home Network - Uplink",
                        "data": array_hour_p_up
                    }]
                }, {
                    "dataset": [{
                        "seriesname": "Guest Network - Downlink",
                        "data": array_hour_g_down
                    }, {
                        "seriesname": "Guest Network - Uplink",
                        "data": array_hour_g_up
                    }]
                }]
            }
        });

});


</script>
```

---

I wrap my code around **ajax.done()** because I don't want my page load to wait for that data and rendering the chart as soon as the data arrive. But now I face another issue.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: granular_time_network_day is not defined`

---

## Error

[image]

```
    $('#granular-time').on('click', function() {
        $('#granular-total-view').hide();
        $('#granular-time-view').fadeIn('slow');
        granular_time_network_day.render();
        granular_time_device_day.render();
        $('#btn-interval').prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Did I do anything wrong on my Ajax?

Should I look into promise or something like that?

Comment: there's no need to have functions inside the `.done()` callback - I would guess that the call isn't completed yet when you try to click it

Comment: while `granular_time_network_day` refers to a function u should call it like: `granular_time_network_day().render();`

Comment: @tonylefler : I hope you don't mind answering your suggestion. I'll make sure to accept it. I'm not sure how to adjust it base on your comment.

Comment: @messerbill : Okay, I'll try, and will keep you posted !

Comment: @messerbill : I still get the same error after doing as you suggested `granular_time_network_day().render();`

Comment: @tonylefler : Can you give a bit more hints please ?

Comment: @ihue see my edits on my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined granular_time_network_day outside of your ajax.done function

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking to see if granular_time_network_day exists before calling render.

Example:

```
$('#interval-day').on('click',function(){
    if (granular_time_network_day) {
        granular_time_network_day.render();
    } else {
        //tell user that the data is still being retrieved or handle another way
    }
});
```

I did notice a potential other problem related to the variable being declared in the done call - granular_time_network_day will be in scope only for the done function. It would work out to declare it outside the done function, so that the click handler will be able to access it when the ajax call is complete.

Answer (score 0):

define the function outside of your `.done()` callback so the click is aware of it even if the call hasn't completed yet.

### EDIT

You don't need to check to see if a function is available, you need to check and see if you have the data yet from the `$.ajax` call:

```
var data = null;

$.ajax().done(function(data) {
    // assign data
    data = data;
});

$('#granular-time'.on('click', function() {
    // check to see if you have data
    if (data) {
        // do your stuff
        var granular_time_network_day = new FusionCharts({
        "type": "msstackedcolumn2d",
        "renderAt": "granular-time-network",
        "width": "100%",
        "dataFormat": "json",
            ....
        })
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

## window.

Turn out that `window.` save my life, and the answer that I am looking for.

Here is my final script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}'});
ajax.done(function (data) {

    console.log(data)

    var array_hour_g_down = [];
    var array_hour_g_up = [];
    var array_hour_p_down = [];
    var array_hour_p_up = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.hour_g_up.length; i++) {

        array_hour_g_down[i] = {"value":data.hour_g_down[i]};
        array_hour_g_up[i]   = {"value":data.hour_g_up[i]};
        array_hour_p_down[i] = {"value":data.hour_p_down[i]};
        array_hour_p_up[i]   = {"value":data.hour_p_up[i]};

    }

    window.granular_time_network_day = new FusionCharts({
        "type": "msstackedcolumn2d",
        "renderAt": "granular-time-network",
        "width": "100%",
        "dataFormat": "json",
        "dataSource": {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Time-Based Bandwidth Usage",
            "subcaption": "Daily View",
            "xaxisname": data.month + ' ' + data.dth + ',' + ' '+ data.year,
            "yaxisname": "Bandwidth (in Megabytes)",
            "paletteColors": color_home_down+','+color_home_up+','+color_guest_down+','+color_guest_up,
                    // "numbersuffix": "MB",
                    "showvalues": "0",
                    "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                    "borderAlpha": "20",
                    "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                    "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                    "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                    "legendShadow": "0",
                    "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
                    "showXAxisLine": "1",
                    "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
                    "divlineColor": "#999999",
                    "divLineDashed": "1",
                    "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                    "subcaptionFontSize": "14"
                },
                "categories": [{
                    "category": [{
                        "label": "12am-2am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "2am-4am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "4am-6am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "6am-8am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "8am-10am"
                    }, {
                        "label": "10am-12pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "12pm-2pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "2pm-4pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "4pm-6pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "6pm-8pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "8pm-10pm"
                    }, {
                        "label": "10pm-12am"
                    }]
                }],
                "dataset": [{
                    "dataset": [{
                        "seriesname": "Home Network - Downlink",
                        "data": array_hour_p_down
                    }, {
                        "seriesname": "Home Network - Uplink",
                        "data": array_hour_p_up
                    }]
                }, {
                    "dataset": [{
                        "seriesname": "Guest Network - Downlink",
                        "data": array_hour_g_down
                    }, {
                        "seriesname": "Guest Network - Uplink",
                        "data": array_hour_g_up
                    }]
                }]
            }
        });

});


</script>
```

---

I'm no longer getting the error.